# Angular argument of type 'HttpEvent<any>' is not assignable to parameter

Tags: angular, http, httpclient, rest

In my authentication service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpSentEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { User } from '../_models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    private payload:any;
    public header:any;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;
    
 

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
this.header= new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With")
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .set('content-type', 'application/json'); 
        
    }
    
    public get currentUserValue(): User {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }
    login(name: string, password: string) {
        this.payload={ "auth": {
            "identity": {
              "methods": ["password"],
              "password": {
                "user": {
                  "name": name,
                  
                  "password": password
                }
              }
            },
            
          }
        }
        
        this.header={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
       
      return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}auth/tokens`,this.payload,{headers: this.header,observe: 'response' })
            .pipe(map(response  => {
              const user = response.body;
              const token = response.headers.get('x-subject-token');
              localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                console.log(response.headers.get('x-subject-token'));
                //console.log(token);
                return user;
            }));
    }
    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

here in the  **this.currentUserSubject.next(user);** the user shows error as **Argument of type 'HttpEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'User': name, password**

this is my model user.ts

```
export class User {
    
    token?: string;
    
}
```

Can anyone help in this, I'm using angular 9.

Comment: try to change `this.http.post(...., this.payload, this.header)` to `this.http.post(...., this.payload, {headers: this.header}) . HttpOptions is an object which has a property as `headers`

Comment: I explained it better as an answer. You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem while setting `HttpOptions`. It is a class which has a property as `HttpHeaders`. But you are implementing it wrong.

You need to change

```
this.http.post(...., this.payload, this.header)
```

to

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post(...., this.payload, {headers: httpHeaders})
```

Why you are getting this error?

`HttpOptions` also has a property which is `observe`. Default value of it is `body` but you can set it to `response`. When you set it to `response`, Angular gives response completely (with status code, response headers, body, etc.)

I think you broke it with implementing `HttpOptions` wrong.

**UPDATE**

If you want to reach `response headers` you need to add `observe: 'response'` to the `HttpOptions` like

```
 const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post(...., this.payload, { headers: httpHeaders, observe: 'response' }).pipe(map(response => {
            const user = response.body;
            const token = response.headers.get('X-Subject-Token');
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
```

Comment: how can I store the X-Subject-Token from my response header. because when I logged to see the data I called it does not contain that token.

Comment: To do it you need to add `observe: 'response'` to the `HttpOptions`. But when you set it you need to change your `map` function as `map(response => user = response.body; token = response.headers.get('X-Subject-Token')`.

Comment: I have added HttpOptions but it showed some error! Can you just show how to add it in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer. If you get any error, please notify me with details. Good Luck. @Ananthakrishna

Comment: `console.log(response.headers.get('X-Subject-Token'));` returns null

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for response headers from network tab of developer console? @Ananthakrishna

Comment: [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/9KTngl.jpg) here it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219403/discussion-between-nevzatopcu-and-ananthakrishna).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with the return type of your api. To confirm it I would recommend you to log the output and based on that take the next step.

```
 return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiUrl+"auth/tokens",this.payload,this.header)
            .pipe(map(user => {
               console.log(user);
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
```

Second option I would suggest you to use the strong type. Create or use the existing User model while hitting the post method

```
return this.http.post<User>(environment.apiUrl+"auth/tokens",this.payload,this.header)
            .pipe(map(user => {
               console.log(user);
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));
```

In both the cases my suspect is response of the API. Because the error clearly there is some issue with conversion.